# Ag grid getLastDisplayedRow() does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I use getLastDisplayedRow() to get grid displyed last row index. And then display the grid by using ensureIndexVisable(lastRowIndex, 'bottom'). The issue is that it always jump down 10 rows to start display(in this case, if you scroll down to the end of the grid, then it wont jump since there is no more row to jump). I googled a little bit and get something not exactly the same but looks similar *https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1360*, which says somehow there is a 10 rowbuffer(a 2016 thread).

I looked up the doc of getLastDisplayedRow(), it does mention

"getFirstDisplayedRow() Get the index of the first displayed row due to scrolling (includes not visible rendered rows in the buffer)"

also got *https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/#5-configure-row-buffer* that explains why and what is about the buffer.

is there a I can config the row buffer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

it is can be configured as grid option like

```
  <AgGridReact
        modules={this.state.modules}
        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
        ensureDomOrder={true}
        suppressColumnVirtualisation={true}
        rowBuffer={this.state.rowBuffer}
        onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
        rowData={this.state.rowData}
      />
```

It is easy, but it took me some time to know the buffer existing. After the change getLastDisplayedRow() with ensureIndexVisable(lastRowIndex, 'bottom') works properly now.